# Can Mobile Vision API's Face Tracking, not Detection, used independent of its CameraSource?

Tags: android, computer-vision, android-camera, face-detection, android-vision

This question is about using [Google's Mobile Vision Face API](https://developers.google.com/vision/face-detection-concepts) on Android.

### The Story (Background) and what I want to do

I am trying to implement a function that detects faces in a camera view, and overlaying images on those faces.

Now, I have already successfully implemented such feature by using Mobile Vision API's **[Face Detection](https://developers.google.com/vision/android/detect-faces-tutorial)**. Its mechanism is like this:

1. A CameraView (I am using
       [Fotoapparat](https://github.com/Fotoapparat/Fotoapparat) here) that
       can pass each camera frame in a callback
2. I turn that frame into a `Bitmap`
3. The bitmap is passed to Mobile Vision API for face detection
4. When Face is detected, I get its position and size
5. Using that position information, draw something on another custom View.

The problem is, **the above process obviously takes too much time**. I can only update the overlaying image position 3-5 times every second, even less frequent on slower devices.

By looking at the profiling, the most heavy method is, surprisingly, step 3 (Face detetction). It takes an average of 100ms to perform once.
Second heavy method is converting the NV21 frame into a Bitmap object, which takes around 90ms.
Summing up everything now I get an update FPS of 3~5.

But other than that, every thing works perfectly - image can be captured in **high quality**, with **auto focus** and **pinch zooming**.

### How about Face Tracking?

On the other hand, Mobile Vision API provides another API - [Face Tracking](https://developers.google.com/vision/android/face-tracker-tutorial).

In Google's sample app, the tracking is very fast, it follows almost instantaneously with the faces in the camera preview. As stated in the document, this is because the mechanism is completely different - instead of detecting faces on each frame, once a face is detected, the position simply follows its movement without performing any face detection.

But it fact such mechanism is good enough in my use case!

However, by looking at the sample code, it looks like I have to use its built-in implementation of `CameraSource`. This can be find in the code below:

```
    mCameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(context, detector)
            .setRequestedPreviewSize(640, 480)
            .setFacing(CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_BACK)
            .setRequestedFps(30.0f)
            .build();
```

`detector` is the main character here, and it is only used here when passing to `CameraSource`. **It looks like I have to stick to using this `CameraSource`.**

However, although this camera source has `takePicture()` method, I cannot find any way to implement **auto focus and zooming**.

### Finally, the question

My ultimate objective is to implement the feature I have mentioned in the beginning, with the below requirements:

1. High quality image captured
2. Auto focus
3. Zoom
4. Fast face position
   update (About 10 times in a second is good enough)

1-3 can be done using Face Detection, but not 4;
While 4 can be done using Face Tracker, but not 1-3.

Is there a way to accomplish all 1-4? I welcome any suggestion even if it is to use another library instead of Mobile Vision.

Thanks for reading such long question till the end!

Comment: How to get camera preview using CameraSource? ..so that on preview i can recognise the faces ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CameraSource.java is available [on GitHub](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/blob/master/visionSamples/barcode-reader/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/samples/vision/barcodereader/ui/camera/CameraSource.java) under a permissive [Apache license](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0). Feel free to add auto-focus and zoom.

Comment: Later I found that the smoothness in the sample is (probably) due to the fact that it sets the preview size to a rather small resolution. With that resolution I can also get a much higher FPS, which is noticed when I am using the front camera. Thanks for your answer anyway, I definitely missed this file on the Github, I thought it was not open-sourced.

Comment: Theoretically, the barcodereader and facedetection CameraSource classes could be different, but for all practical purposes, the former is good enough.